# PHPexcel output in excel file with bad character encoding

Tags: character-encoding, phpexcel

I am using utf8 char encoding - `mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8')` in PHP file and `utf8_czech_ci` in MySQL.

I am programming on Windows computer and here is no problem. When I move my PHP application to Linux server, there is problem with bad character encoding (czech characters like ščřž...) in output Excel file.

Comment: Are you actually using the PHPExcel library? If so, you need to ensure that your values are UTF-8 before inserting them into cells... but it sounds as though your problem is before that point

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, I'm using PHPexcel version 1.7.9.  in MySQL DB are values stored as `utf8_czech_ci` and are took from there by `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Then they are pass to excel sheet by `setCellValue`. Where do you thing is the problem?

Comment: I don't know for certain; but if PHPExcel is passed correct utf-8 values, then it has no coding issues because it is explicitly written to work with utf-8... you'll only have this problem if the values aren't valid utf-8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: What does [mb_detect_encoding()](http://www.php.net/function.mb-detect-encoding) make of your strings?

Comment: mb_detect_encoding() output UTF-8 on my Win computer. I will try to send it to colegues on Linux server and then write result here

Comment: @MarkBaker so, colegues changed from changed from Excel5 to Excel2007 and they said now it's working. I have no access to Linux server to try something. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your PHP function, I have solved from this command, It will release buffer memory before creating Excel file.

```
 ob_end_clean();
 ob_start();
```